# Как убрать ложное инкрементирование Id при ошибке нарушении уникальности БД

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

Есть такая таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При ошибке 409 (нарушение уникальности email), id все равно растет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И принимается значение уже не 2, к примеру, а 3, хотя в БД 1 запись.

@transactional не спасает

Comment: Хорошее, правильное поведение! Бойтесь ту БД, которая переиспользует айдишники.

Comment: чем вам мешает растущий ID? Проверяйте наличие почты прежде чем делать вставку. Вернее смысла вставки, наверное, не будет тогда.

Comment: Так и сделал @teran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Документация PostgreSQL о типах serial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) явно говорит об этом:

> Note
>
> Because smallserial, serial and bigserial are implemented using
> sequences, there may be "holes" or gaps in the sequence of values
> which appears in the column, even if no rows are ever deleted. A value
> allocated from the sequence is still "used up" even if a row
> containing that value is never successfully inserted into the table
> column. This may happen, for example, if the inserting transaction
> rolls back. See nextval() in Section 9.17 for details.

Вольный перевод:

> Заметка
>
> Поскольку smallserial, serial и bigserial используют
> последовательности sequences, они могут оставлять "дыры" или пропуски
> значений для колонки, даже если строки не были удалены. Значение в
> последовательности растет, даже если полученное из неё значение не
> используется успешно при вставке. К примеру, если транзакция на
> вставку откатилась. Смотрите Section 9.17 для подробностей.

Ну и секция 9.17 говорит о том, что последовательности созданы так, чтобы не блокировать параллельные транзакции во время выполнения. Поэтому значение, полученное из nextval не восстанавливается обратно.

Вообще закладываться на автоинкрементное поле ID и что его последовательности будут идти друг за другом по порядку является плохой идеей. Если вам все же очень это нужно, то придется отказаться от этих типов и использовать свои <s>костыли</s> реализации.